# TTF font type doesnt support in IE11

Tags: css, fonts, truetype

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd19j.png]

`.ttf` fonts aren't supported in IE9 or below .Can someone suggest me something to  get this fixed using css3?

Answer (score 0):

Declare multiple font extensions so it will be supported by IE9?

Pseudo example code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Use [FontSquirrels generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create those, should give you the required CSS as well.